# Нужен ли обратный адрес при почтовой SMTP рассылке?

Tags: smtp, email, рассылка, smtp-server

В настройке почтовых серверов нуб, прошу не пинать. Хочу настроить SMTP сервер для рассылки уведомлений (всё белое с разрешения пользователей) но настройка для отправки и создание своих почтовых ящиков для приёма писем я так понял это разные вещи, ящик свой я не планировал делать, но тогда если кто-то ответит роботу приславшему письмо с no-reply@mydomain.com (а такие обязательно найдутся) то что будет в этом случае? Или свои ящики на моём сервере в любом случае придётся создавать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов проверки входящей почты на спам состоит в том, что сервер, получивший письмо, *пытается* отправить письмо в ответ на тот же адрес, с которого он его получил (именно пытается, фактической отправки не происходит, посылается лишь несколько команд). Если в ответ он получит сообщение, что ящика не существует - то полученное письмо, возможно, является спамом.

Поэтому - обратный адрес **нужен**. Если сервер, с которого вы будете отправлять письма, будет отвечать отказом на попытку послать письмо на тот ящик, с которого ведётся рассылка - у некоторых ваших получателей ваши письма могут попадать в спам.

Впрочем вы можете не обязательно делать ящик с именно таким же именем, а настроить перенаправление на какой-то инной ящик. Главное, что бы ваш почтовый сервер был готов принять письмо для адреса no-reply@mydomain.com.